# Consulo IDE for C# mono and Unity3d, IS IT POSSIBLE?

Tags: c#, intellij-idea, mono, ide, unity-game-engine

I stumbled upon [Consulo IDE](https://github.com/consulo/consulo) which is currently in development. It is an Intellij IDEA based IDE with available plugins for c# and mono.

The only problem is I don't know how to configure the IDE so I can use it with mono C# for Unity3d. Is somebody using this Consulo IDE alternative for Unity3D? If yes, how do I set it up to work with unity and mono c#?

I DID READ THE WIKI.

Comment: Beware that even though it's based on the IntelliJ platform, this IDE *is not* developed by JetBrains, so you can't assume it has the same quality as JetBrains' products (it may though, I haven't tested it). Also, did you read their wiki (https://github.com/consulo/consulo/wiki/Before-developing)?

Comment: The development work I do in MonoDevelop is 98% writing text. I spent an hour to get the code auto-formatter right. Very occassionally I need to right-click to refactor or extract a property. That's it. There's really little an IDE needs to do to work well with Unity (in fact if only debugging were easier in another IDE I would switch immediately because THAT is the most important aspect of an IDE). To think you would voluntarily use an IDE that can't debug Unity apps kind of renders your point moot.

Comment: @Nebelmann the wiki got a little better now =) https://github.com/consulo/consulo/wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's been a long time since last answer and I still stumbled upon this thread, I must clarify few things:

Right now configuring Untiy3D in Consulo is as simple as installing Unity3D plugin from plugin repository (can be done inside IDE, no need to google anything).

What's more, debugging Unity is also pretty simple: you just press "Attach to Unity3D" button, select Unity process and it's done - you can set up breakpoints wherever you want.

Basically, Consulo is out of the box ready to use IDE for Unity (in my experience it's even more useful than JetBrains' Project Rider due to better plugin and has better performance on my Linux installation). Of course, it's pretty limited if it comes to other C# usecases, like WPF.

Answer (score 9):

Watch video how setup Consulo at first start, create and run Unity project

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRAzz5wxk90

Comment: But for now all builds are not available. Sorry for that. I will fix it in near future

Comment: Resolving is fine for the moment. Building is not required because Unity handles that and I can use the MonoDevelop debugger. What I am interested is the Intellij Idea workflow. I will give it a try as soon as the download becomes available. Thanks a lot for the hardwork developing it ;)

Comment: Please later - email me, i will reply you. I am not checking stackoverflow, due no popularity)

Comment: Post a new answer and explain how to configure Consulo for UNITY3D and I will mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I'll give it a try right now and I'll be back with a feedback, good job !

Comment: Ok, let me known about problems. But dont try 'Unity Debug' its very bugged for now

Comment: It's amazing and it's working great on Windows 8.1 and Mac OS X Yosemite. I've found few small bugs but 99,99% it's working well. You did a good job and you saved a lot of lifes !

Comment: Guys me need feedback, i cant check all. If u found issue report pls at https://github.com/consulo/consulo-csharp/issues

Comment: @VISTALL I know that you want all feedback/questions/comments to go through github, but I was curious if you could put up a doc somewhere describing how to set up the environment variables in Consulo. (It's why I am here, tbh.) I'm trying to figure out how to use it as my go to ide, as I have recently migrated to linux from windows...

Comment: @Michieal Hello. Here exists https://consulo.help/plugins/consulo.unity3d/setup/ but maybe be It missed something which I don't known. You can say me what problem you catch? And I will say what need todo, and maybe update help doc if need. Thanks

Comment: @VISTALL Hello :D I can't find it now, but it was asking me for $variables, like the project directory and the output directory to run the project. Then again, it seems that I no longer have anything but console applications in the Templates. Hmmn. And, the new Console project (C#) causes an IDE error; I sent in a report...
And... the open/import project fails miserably. I have to use the recent projects list on the left side.

Comment: $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$ is one of the variables that it asks for, but it fails on all of it.

Comment: @Michieal just remove $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$ inside Run Configurations.  Also drop it from here (https://klikr.org/703a63e4d8c08c8bf8a3b4518893.png). It's some migration bug. Empty working dir value supported

Comment: @VISTALL Thank you. I realized that I folowed your suggestion, and ran with it, and forgot to say thank you. So... THANK YOU!!!!!!! :D